# how to plot a the given function?

Tags: matlab, plot

i have the fallowing matlab code

```
close all
Pu=1;
No=1e-8;
B=20e6;
u=1:20;
C_CDMA=u*B*log2(1+Pu./(B*No+(u-1)*Pu));
plot(u,C_CDMA/1e6);hold on
xlabel('Noise Power Spectral Density (No)')
ylabel('Capacity (Mbps)')
legend('CDMA','OFDMA')
```

the equation C_CDMA should be calculated for each value of (u) . and then plot the result as the values of the function with u values but this code give me the fallowing error
" error using m times Inner matrix dimensions must agree".
what is the wrong ?

Comment: Other than your original error, I have some doubts .  ⓵  logarithm of what base are you calculating here? In your code, it is actually logarithm to the base 2 (not log10 or natural log). I hope you know that ⓶ What output are you expecting with this: `legend('CDMA','OFDMA')`? What do you mean by adding two legends here when you're plotting just one array?

Comment: The error can be avoided by replacing the line in your code in which you're calculating `C_CDMA` with this: `C_CDMA=u*B.*log2((1+(ones(1,20)*Pu))./((ones(1,20)*B*No)+(u-1)*Pu));` ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: well the legend is an error i keep the same legend from previous plotting but i am calculating wireless channel capacity with different number of users (u) which give me decreasing in capacity with increasing the number of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope simple solution would be to put u in for loop as follows

```
close all
Pu=1;
No=1e-8;
B=20e6;
C_CDMA = zeros(1,20)

for u=1:20
    C_CDMA(u) = u*B*log2((1+Pu)/(B*No+(u-1)*Pu));
end

u=1:20;
figure,
plot(u,C_CDMA/1e6);hold on
xlabel('Noise Power Spectral Density (No)')
ylabel('Capacity (Mbps)')
legend('CDMA','OFDMA')
```

why two legends for a single  graph

Comment: i tried this but its give me only one value of the C_CDMA . i guess that the problem with the multiplication at the beginning  C_CDMA=u*B*log2(1+Pu./(B*No+(u-1)*Pu))                                                 because when i remove the u from the multiplication its works

Comment: if you want to see different values of C_CDMA remove ";' from

    C_CDMA(u) = u*B*log2((1+Pu)/(B*No+(u-1)*Pu))